# Cannot acces UsersProfile in Web.Security ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm tryign to reach all the users in database, to show theirs names, ids, etc.

I do:

```
 using(UsersContext uc = new UsersContext())
        {
            var dupa = uc.UserProfiles.ToList();
        }
```

but it doesn't give any result, (Count =0) (but i have a couple users in the database, cause i created them and I can login with no problem)

Comment: Are you using Membership provider in asp.net?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SimpleMembershipInitializer

Comment: Can you post your Models, UsersContext and ConnectionString?